# Weird lines when using display: inline-block; inside <a> tags

Tags: html, css

Whenever I create a `div` with `display: inline-block;` style inside an `a` tag, I get these weird lines at the bottom, that show up for no apparent reason at all. The problem seems to reproduce itself only when I place the `div` inside the `a` tags, instead of vice versa, but the reason I have an `a` tag surrounding my divs is to make buttons out of them.

It's kind of hard to explain, but I've made a fiddle to reproduce the problem so I can show it to you.

http://jsfiddle.net/bcnobel/6L92C/2/
Note the black lines between the divs.

Has anybody had this as well before?
Does anybody know a simple (yet elegant) workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're links, which by default have `text-decoration:underline;`. Set `text-decoration:none;` on the `a` tags and you'll be fine.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6L92C/5/).

Comment: I can't believe I haven't thought about removing the text decoration... I guess I figured that I used no text, and therefor that this shouldn't be the problem. Your solution solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @GabiBarrientos: Just to clarify this answer in case you are relatively new to html and css, the default for an `<a>` element is to have an underline because that is the standard for identifying a link, which is what the `<a>` is used for. Of course many sites override this default behavior (StackOverflow shows it only on hover).

Comment: I know that the underline is the standard for `<a>` tags, however I guess it just must have slipped my mind, since I only have a `<div>` tag inside my `<a>` tags, instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

in  style use this

```
 <a href="r#" style="text-decoration: none">
```